# How to share QR generated image in Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android, qr-code, zxing

Im trying to share my qr generated image but when I try it, the QR code image is not appearing on the selected share method.[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tabft.jpg)

Im tryin to ceate a function where, when a user register it will generate a QR code and pop it up using a dialog box, then when the user click the Okay button on the dialog box it should share the QR code via the selected method of the user. I tried following a tutorial on YoutTube by Android Tutorials: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eSi28xqGjbE, the share function is working but it doesnt show the generated QR code in the selected method for sharing the image.

```
public void showQR() {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.cutome_dialog_layout);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_dialog_background));
        }
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        dialog.setCancelable(false); //Optional
        dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation; //Setting the animations to dialog

        Button Okay = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_okay);
        Button Cancel = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
        ImageView qr_image = dialog.findViewById(R.id.qrcode);

        MultiFormatWriter multiFormatWriter = new MultiFormatWriter();

        try {
            BitMatrix bitMatrix = multiFormatWriter.encode(studentNumber.getText().toString()+ " ," +fullName.getText().toString(), BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 300, 300);

            BarcodeEncoder barcodeEncoder = new BarcodeEncoder();
            Bitmap bitmap = barcodeEncoder.createBitmap(bitMatrix);

            qr_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        }
        catch (WriterException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }


        Okay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {
                    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) qr_image.getDrawable();
                    Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
                    shareImageAndText(bitmap);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterStudent.this, "share image problem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        Cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(RegisterStudent.this, "Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }

    private void shareImageAndText(Bitmap bitmap) {
        Uri uri = getImageToShare(bitmap);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Please dont share your QR Code to anyone");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "QR Code");
        intent.setType("images/*");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share via"));
    }

    private Uri getImageToShare(Bitmap bitmap) {
        File folder = new File(getCacheDir(), "images");
        Uri uri = null;
        try {
        folder.mkdirs();
        File file = new File(folder, "image.jpg");
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fileOutputStream);
        fileOutputStream.flush();
        fileOutputStream.close();

        uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.example.myapplication", file);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return uri;
    }
```

Please help me on how can i share my QR-generated code.

Expected output.
[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZH6e1.jpg)

Comment: `the QR code image is not appearing on the selected share method.output` Pretty unclear where you wanna see that qr image.

Comment: I want the qr image to also show on the output with the text, like what the tutorial shows.

Comment: What do you consider to be the output? The receiver gets you email and sees the qr?

Comment: My expected output is that the receiver can get the generated QR. Not necessarily thru email.

Comment: What is output,?

Comment: It's in the "expected output" image in my post. Please check it out. Thank you!

Comment: What does this have to do with generating a qr image? Can you test this with an image you pick from device?

Comment: I tried putting a value on my XML file but its still not showing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```java
intent.setType("images/*");
```

with:

```java
intent.setType("image/jpeg");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

*You* are the one supplying the content, so *you* need to be the one indicating the MIME type of that content. Also, you need to give permission to the other app to access that content.

Comment: I tried doing this and the QR image is still not showing.

Comment: @MisterBlueBanana: I just realized that you are also missing a permission -- see the updated example.

Comment: Still doesn't work it seems like the problem is that the getImageToShare() method cannot get the QR-generated image.